# python socket tchat issue

Tags: python, sockets

I started to code in python with sockets and I have a little problem for my chat script.

Server script

```
import pickle, socket, struct, sys, threading

SERVERADDRESS = ("localhost", 6030)

class helloChatServer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__server = socket.socket()
        self.users = []

        try:
            self.__server.bind(SERVERADDRESS)
        except socket.error:
            print('Bind failed {}'.format(socket.error))

        self.__server.listen(10)

    def exit(self):
        self.__server.close()

    def run(self):
        print( "Listening... {}".format(SERVERADDRESS))
        while True:
            client, addr = self.__server.accept()
            try:
                threading.Thread(target=self._handle, args=(client, addr)).start()
            except OSError:
                print('Error during processing the message')


    def _handle(self, client, addr):
        print('Client connected with {}:{}'.format(addr[0], str(addr[1])))
        self.users.append(addr)

        while True:

            data = client.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            client.send(data)

        client.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    helloChatServer().run()
```

Client script

```
import pickle, socket, struct, sys, threading

SERVERADDRESS = (socket.gethostname(), 6050)

class helloChatClient():

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=5000, pseudo="Visitor"):
        self.__socket = socket.socket()
        self.__socket.bind((host, port))
        self.__pseudo = pseudo

        print('Listening on {}:{}'.format(host, port))

    def run(self):
        handlers = {
            '/exit': self._exit,
            '/quit': self._quit,
            '/join': self._join,
            '/send': self._send
        }
        self.__running = True
        self.__address = None
        threading.Thread(target=self._receive).start()
        while self.__running:
            line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip() + ' '
            # Extract the command and the param
            command = line[:line.index(' ')]
            param = line[line.index(' ')+1:].rstrip()
            # Call the command handler
            if command in handlers:
                try:
                    handlers[command]() if param == '' else handlers[command](param)
                except:
                    print("Error during the execution of the message")
            else:
                print('Command inconnue:', command)

    def _exit(self):
        self.__running = False
        self.__address = None
        self.__socket.close()

    def _quit(self):
        self.__address = None

    def _join(self, param):
        if self.__pseudo == "Visitor":
            self.__pseudo = input("Choose a username: ")

        tokens = param.split(' ')
        if len(tokens) == 2:
            try:
                self.__address = (tokens[0], int(tokens[1]))
                self.__socket.connect(self.__address)
                print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
                print('Connected at {}:{}'.format(*self.__address))
                print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
            except OSError:
                print("Error during the sending of the message")

        self.__socket.send(self.__pseudo.encode())

    def _send(self, param):
        if self.__address is not None:
            try:
                message = param.encode()
                totalsent = 0
                while totalsent < len(message):
                    sent = self.__socket.send(message[totalsent:])
                    totalsent += sent
                print(self.__socket.recv(1024).decode())
            except OSError:
                print('Error during the reception of the message')

    def _receive(self):
        while self.__running:
            try:
                data = self.__socket.recv(1024).decode()
                print(data)
            except socket.timeout:
                pass
            except OSError:
                return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        helloChatClient(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]),  sys.argv[3]).run()
    else:
        helloChatClient().run()
```

Well when I run the script on the terminal, I see this.

Server

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Saikou:labo2 saikouah$ python3.4 helloChatServer.py
En écoute sur... ('MacBook-Pro-de-Saikou.local', 6030)
Client connected with 127.0.0.1:5004
Il y a actuellement 1 connecté
b'bluebeel'
b'hello'
```

Client

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Saikou:labo2 saikouah$ python3.4 helloChatClient.py localhost 5004 bluebeel
Écoute sur localhost:5004
/join MacBook-Pro-de-Saikou.local 6030
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Connecté à MacBook-Pro-de-Saikou.local:6030
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/send hello
bluebeel
```

On the client terminal he doesn't print me hello but bluebeel. I made several test and he took me every time the previous one message. Looks like he is late.

Someone can help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM ANALYSIS**

Your code fails in `_receive` function:

```
data = self.__socket.recv(1024).decode()
```

This line throws `OSError` because you try to call `.recv` **before** connecting to the server. Thus the exception handler is fired and the function exits. So what happens is that after calling

```
threading.Thread(target=self._receive).start()
```

function `_receive` exits **before** you call `/join`. So watch what happens

1. You call `/join`.
2. `bluebeel` is send to the server
3. Server receives it and sends it back to the client
4. **But** `_receive` function is no longer there. So the message is "stacked" on the socket (it will wait for next `.recv()` call)
5. You call `/send hello`
6. Server receives `hello` and sends it back
7. Client calls `print(self.__socket.recv(1024).decode())` in `_send` method
8. **But** `.recv` retrieves **the first message** that is stacked on the socket. In that case it is not `hello`, it is `bluebeel`.

Now this schema continues to work. You send message, server pings it back but there's always 1 message in front of the received one. The "late" message.

---

**SOLUTION**

One way of solving this issue is to call

```
threading.Thread(target=self._receive).start()
```

in `._join` method **after** `.connect`. Remember to remove `print(self.__socket.recv(1024).decode())` from `_send` method, otherwise it will block `stdin`.

Of course you will have problems when issuing multiple `/join` commands. To properly address that you would have to keep track of `_receive` thread and kill it at the begining of `._join` method. This however is beyond the scope of this question IMHO.

---

**SIDE NOTE**

Don't ever handle exceptions like you did. This is wrong:

```
try:
    data = self.__socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
except socket.timeout:
    pass
except OSError:
    return
```

At least do this:

```
import traceback

try:
    data = self.__socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
except socket.timeout:
    traceback.print_exc()
except OSError:
    traceback.print_exc()
    return
```